# Stack equivelant for tester questions

Tags: cucumber

I have some questions relating to cucumber and am looking for the relevant forum to ask questions.

http://cukes.info/

Is it this one?

Thanks

Ian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the tag has been used 1216 times already.

There exists a beta site on Software QA and testing, but cucumber was not tagged there yet.
[A few questions refer to the tool/method, though.](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/search?q=cucumber)

Comment: Thanks Johan - I got slated the slast time I posted a q on the wrong forum, so thanks for taking a look.